# How can one analyze cacheline contention for multithreaded programs on Linux/AMD? Like "perf c2c" can for Intel

Tags: linux, cpu-cache, perf, amd-processor, false-sharing

With Intel chips, it is possible to analyze cacheline contention using the "perf c2c" command? Is there anything similar that can be used with AMD processors?

Specifically, for the case where a core attempts to read a cacheline that is currently in "modified" state in some other cores L1 cache. Is there a tool that can profile these and similar events on AMD?

Comment: AMD uProf (https://developer.amd.com/amd-uprof/) claims support for cache analysis on both Windows and Linux

Answer (score 2):

This was added to the Linux kernel and perf in version 6.1
https://www.phoronix.com/news/Linux-6.1-Perf